# Random Selection from Names based on Weightage

Tags: java, arrays, list, random

I have a list of Options and their values as below

Ram      25%
Mohamed  25%
Samuel   25%
Karthik  25%

Based on this I need to Print some 20 rows.

So the result should have all the four names printed 5 times each making 20 names.

For ease, I have given the number of result rows as 20 and the options are equally distributed as 25% each. They all may vary.

I am looking for good program in Java.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's random over here? You have a target number (20 in the case above) and a percentage of selections (25%) which should total up to the target number. Won't simply getting the count of selections by division from target number and then adding to list `count` times give you desired result?

Comment: *FYI:* The very nature of *random* means that you very likely will not print each name 5 times. Some might be printed 4 or fewer times, while others will print 6 or more times. --- Or did you not actually want *random*? If not, **edit** the question and remove any use of the word, to clarify your intent.

Comment: So what's the use of percentage then? Is it like an upper limit to the number of times an option can come?

Comment: The percentage decides the number of times a name should be displayed in the result